# Equality of Form and Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a collection of MDI forms, where there are different objects (Form1,Form2 etc). Is there any fast way how to compare whather selected form (using FOR cycle for iterating through form collection) is Form1,Form2..?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  foreach(Form f in AllForms)
  {
      if(f is From1)
         return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a straightforward thing to do, what is the actual problem you are facing?

Have you tried a regular compare?

```
foreach(Form f in AllForms) {
  if(f == myForm1)
    return true;
}
```

Use `f == myForm1` if you already have a single instance of `Form1` named `myForm1` that you are comparing against or `f is Form1` if you are looking for "any" `Form1`, without already having one somewhere.